# inserting problems in Dreamweaver

Tags: html, dreamweaver

I have some problems with Dreamweaver, when I'm inserting new image with width 1000 pixels (for example) in the table with width 1000 pixels, I receive the following cell padding:

```
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
x 
x -----------------
x |//here image
x |
x |
x

<body>
<table width="1000" align="center" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" class="main_border">
  <tr>
    <td><img src="./img/canyon.gif" width="1000" height="150" alt="header"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><img src="img/footer.gif" alt="footer" width="1000" height="20" /></td>
  </tr>
</table>
</body>
```

similar problem:

http://www.justskins.com/forums/problem-with-white-space-31439.html

can somebody explain why? thanks in advancems/problem-with-white-space-31439.html

Comment: Can you explain me why you use a table ? =P

Comment: I don't see any cell padding?

Comment: @MatTheCat: I can't understand your question, I want to create my site inside table, is it something wrong with this idea?

Comment: This will make you understand ;) http://webdesign.about.com/od/layout/a/aa111102a.htm

Comment: @MatTheCat: thank you very musch for the nice article, I'll change my design, anyway, want to know about this problem, can you help?

Comment: So isn't that due to page margins?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This used to be called `cellspacing` and `cellpadding` which needed to be set to 0. In CSS, as per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/339146/why-are-cellspacing-and-cellpadding-not-css-styles):

```
table.main_border { border-collapse: collapse; }
table.main_border td {  padding: 0;}
```

that should fix it. If it doesn't,  please show your CSS as well (namely that of `body` and `main_border`).

As pointed out in the comments, using tables for layout is regarded a bad practice in most cases nowadays. Web designers are encouraged to use alternatives (should be very easy in this case).