# Table border size - CSS/HTML

Tags: html, css, html-table, border

Is it possible to extend a cell's border width/height so that it joins with the border of surrounding table?

I have this:

```
<table width="270px" style="border: 1px;">
   <tbody width="270px">
        <tr>
            <th colspan="3" style="border: 1px;">
                Header
            </th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="border: 1px;" valign="middle">
                Left-hand cell
            </td>  
            <td valign="middle">
                Right-hand cell
            </td>
            <td>
                Left-hand cell
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

What is happening is the inner borders don't meet the outer border - there is a slight gap.

Can I get these border to meet?

Comment: Just add cellspacing='0' to your table and use padding for cells.

Comment: Thanks AR that solved the issue. Do you want to submit it as an answer so I can mark it as the answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this and let me know:

```
<table width="270px" style="border: 1px;" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
   <tbody width="270px">
        <tr>
            <th colspan="3" style="border: 1px;">
                Header
            </th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="border: 1px;" valign="middle">
                Left-hand cell
            </td>  
            <td valign="middle">
                Right-hand cell
            </td>
            <td>
                Left-hand cell
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 4):

Have a look at CSS [`border-collapse`](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/border-collapse).

```
table 
{ 
    border-collapse: collapse; 
}
```

Also, have a look at this answer on [how to achieve `cellpadding` and `cellspacing` in CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/339146/why-are-cellspacing-and-cellpadding-not-css-styles).

> *From Ant P.'s answer*:
>
> ... just for completeness:
>
> - `padding` → `cellpadding`
> - `border-spacing` → `cellspacing`
> - `border-collapse` → no HTML equivalent
>
> It's also worth remembering that you can set separate horizontal and vertical values for the CSS ones e.g. border-spacing: 0 1px.

Comment: [No, not 'and cellspacing'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/339146/why-are-cellspacing-and-cellpadding-not-css-styles).

Comment: border-collapse will do the trick. I never worked out if this should be applied to table or td so I always do both. Enlighten me?

Comment: @Marty Wallace: `table` (see that link) although both won't hurt! :)

Comment: Hi border-collapse has actually removed all other effective CSS in the borders. Cellspacing was all I actually needed thanks.

Comment: See Ant P.'s answer in the link. border-spacing is the CSS equivalent. It's best practice to separate design from content.